# QTableView intercepts Key_Down and Key_Up events

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I'm trying to implement "things" on a QTableView. So, I started to override its keyPressEvent method, as it's described everywhere:

```
if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_F2 and self.tableau.hasFocus():
    blabla

elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return and self.tableau.hasFocus():
    blabla

#TEST
elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
    print("right")
elif e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
    print("down")
else:
    print("waza")
```

I can handle the F2 and the Return events, they work. But not the Key_Down event ! The Key_right works as well, but not the Down. I think it's because QTableWidget "intercepts" some of the events. When normal letters are pressed, no event is "emitted" either, for example.

I would like to access all the events (or at least the Up and Down events), how can I do that ?

EDIT:

The view I use is basically a QTableView, which I modified a bit:

```
class ViewPerso(QtGui.QTableView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewPerso, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent = parent


    def currentChanged(self, current, previous):

        index = current.sibling(current.row(), 4)

        try:
            if not index.data() or len(self.parent.vidsSelected()) > 1:
                return
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        self.clicked.emit(current)
        self.scrollTo(current)


    def keyboardSearch(self, search):

        pass
```

I do not use QTableWidget, it doesn't do what I want. I also subclassed the view delegate, but normally (normally), nothing should interfere.

Here is how I use my view: I load a model, a proxy, and then I use my view:

```
    self.modele = ModelPerso()

    self.modele.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)
    self.modele.setTable("videos")
    self.modele.select()

    self.proxy = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
    self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.modele)

    self.tableau = ViewPerso(self)
    self.tableau.setModel(self.proxy)
    self.tableau.setItemDelegate(ViewDelegate(self))
```

I don't know where the keypresses end up, for now, they just disappear. I think (I think), each widget has a way to treat keypresses event, and maybe QTableView ignores the keys up and down ?

Comment: Pleas post more code: do you have separate tableView and tableWidget, or are you talking about something else? Do you know where the keypresses end up, or do they just disappear?

Comment: Done. Maybe I should override the keypressEvent method in the view class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally ended up doing this:

```
class ViewPerso (QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ViewPerso, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def currentChanged (self, current, previous):
        index = current.sibling(current.row(), 4)
        try:
            if not index.data() or len(self.parent.vidsSelected()) > 1:
                return
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.clicked.emit(current)
        self.scrollTo(current)

    def keyboardSearch (self, search):
        pass

    def keyPressEvent (self, e):
        super(ViewPerso, self).keyPressEvent(e)
        e.ignore()
```

The event was probably stuck in ViewPerso, so by overriding its keyPressEvent method like this, I get the usual treatments QTableWidget does on the events, and I the event is propagated to the parent widget, so I can use it again.

I tried to do what you showed in your edit, but it simply does not work for me, I don't really know why. My program is also very big (~10k lines), so the reason could come from anywhere. But thanks to make me realize where the error came from.

Answer (score 0):

For implemented outside class,
You have to override this keyPressEvent method out side.
Like this example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class ViewPerso (QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ViewPerso, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def currentChanged (self, current, previous):
        index = current.sibling(current.row(), 4)
        try:
            if not index.data() or len(self.parent.vidsSelected()) > 1:
                return
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        self.clicked.emit(current)
        self.scrollTo(current)

    def keyboardSearch (self, search):
        pass

class exampleQMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        testQTableWidget = ViewPerso(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(testQTableWidget)
        testQTableWidget.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent

    def keyPressEvent (self, eventQKeyEvent):
        key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_F1:
            print 'Help'
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_F5:
            print 'Reload'
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
            print 'Left'
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            print 'Up'
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
            print 'Right'
        elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Down:
            print 'Down'

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hum, ok, this code works, it prints what it has to. At least now I know the QTableView class treats some keypressEvents. For sure in the Qt code, QTableView's keypressEvent method does something with Qt.Key_Down. So, is there away to use super() in the keyPressEvent method in ViewPerso, and then send the event out of the class, to use it in the main code ? I want to perform actions on the events out of the ViewPerso class.

Comment: You can use SIGNAL() to connect your event outside class. Another way, you can override keyPressEvent method outside class. Please read my last edited post "EDITED: 3/8/2014 11:49".